# Postfix: how to verify sender's MX record

Tags: postfix, mx-record, spam

is it possible to configure Postfix to verify the sender's MX record?

For example: if a mail comes in from `some.sender@example.com` it should look up the MX record(s) for `example.com` and verify that the sending mail server is listed in the MX records.

Is this possible and does it make sense to block spam mails? Or is there another way to stop spam mails pretending to come from trustworthy domains?

Thanks!
Oliver

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A word of warning:

An `MX` record provides information about where email should be *delivered*.  It does not necessarily provide any information about where email *originates*.  It is entirely possible -- even likely -- that mail will be coming from a system that is not listed as an `MX` for the given domain.

`SPF` records, on the other hand, allow you to verify that email is being sent by a system that is an authoritative sender for the domain.

Answer (score 3):

You could configure your spam filtering software to verify [SPF](http://www.openspf.org) records -- This does what you're asking, but in a slightly more intelligent way.

---

Denying mail because the sending server is not listed in the SPF record for a domain doesn't really make sense though -- Many residential ISPs block access to all but their mail server, which means that you may receive mail from domains you correspond with that came from one of those ISPs, and was forced through the ISP's mail infrastructure.

If you're looking for ways to fight spam, consider [SpamAssassin](http://spamassassin.apache.org/) and [ClamAV](http://www.clamav.org), as well as any number of other options like Google's [Postini](http://www.google.com/postini/index.html) service ($).  Dealing with Spam is a specialist subset of system administration, and if you search around on SF or Google you'll find lots of different options that can help you out...

Comment: I have SpamAssassin running but I thought blocking mails with suspicious senders at all could be even more safe :)  
Thanks for your help!